# App crash at launch with API 25 Fatal Signal 6

Tags: android, android-studio

I can run my app without problem on emulator and devices, as long as it is not API 25. After 'Gradle Build Running' has completed, I get the following crash output in the Console:

```html
(Java_libcore_io_Posix_accept__Ljava_io_FileDescriptor_2Ljava_net_SocketAddress_2+168)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at libcore.io.Posix.accept(Native method)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.accept(BlockGuardOs.java:64)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at android.system.Os.accept(Os.java:43)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at android.net.LocalSocketImpl.accept(LocalSocketImpl.java:336)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at android.net.LocalServerSocket.accept(LocalServerSocket.java:90)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at com.android.tools.fd.runtime.Server$SocketServerThread.run(Server.java:150)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422] 
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422] 
A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 4688 (JDWP)

        [ 01-29 09:50:28.405  1201: 1201 W/         ]
        debuggerd: handling request: pid=4679 uid=10071 gid=10071 tid=4688
Disconnected from the target VM, address: 'localhost:8666', transport: 'socket'
```

Comment: Did you try to run your application?

Comment: app gets loaded and I can start it manually in the Emulator. But this wont allow any debugging of course

Comment: When you try to debug your application, app crashes or you couldn't debug?

Comment: it crashes before onCreate in Main Activity is called

Comment: Noone here having the same problem?

Comment: With the latest AS update it works now. Looks like this was an AS bug that they fixed